# Did any of the EU material come from George Lucas?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, canon, george-lucas

Did any of the EU material come from George Lucas?

More specifically, were there any details or facts or events that were:

1. NOT covered in G- or T- canon *works* at all.
2. NOT designed to set up something for the future G or T canon works.
3. Included in C-canon works (aka Extended Universe).
4. Were **explicitly** known to originate fully from George Lucas (e.g. he told/suggested the book author to use a specific idea/fact/event/character).
   Not "approved" by Lucas, but "invented" by him, for lack of a better word.

**NOTEs**:

- Yes, I'm aware that things stated by Lucas automatically count as G-canon even if included in overall-C-canon works. The question is about such facts.
- I'm obviously excluding movie novelizations entirely. They mostly fall under #1/2.
- Yes I'm aware that as of 2014, Disney intends to make canon changes. This question pertains to pre-2013 canon rules.

Comment: I've got an example of the opposite: the first novel was supposedly written by George Lucas himself, so it counts as G canon. Doesn't it? But later we found out that it was actually written by Alan Dean Foster.

Answer (score 4):

By definition ***No***, the "G" of G-canon state for **G** eorge Lucas

> G (George Lucas) canon is absolute canon. This category includes the final releases of the six films, the novelizations of the films, the radio dramas based on the films, the film scripts, **and any material found in any other source (published or not) that comes directly from George Lucas himself.** G canon outranks all other forms of canon.
>
> -- [Wikipedia article about *Star Wars Expanded Universe*, *Official levels of canon* section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Expanded_Universe#Official_levels_of_canon)

And

> **G-canon is George Lucas Canon**; the six Episodes and **any statements by George Lucas (including unpublished production notes from him or his production department that are never seen by the public)**. Elements originating with Lucas in the movie novelizations, reference books, and other sources are also G-canon, though anything created by the authors of those sources is C-canon. When the matter of changes between movie versions arises, the most recently released editions are deemed superior to older ones, as they correct mistakes, improve consistency between the two trilogies, and express Lucas's current vision of the Star Wars universe most closely. The deleted scenes included on the DVDs are also considered G-canon (when they're not in conflict with the movie).
>
> -- [Wookieepedia article about *Canon*, *Canon in the Holocron continuity database* section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon#Canon_in_the_Holocron_continuity_database)

Comment: Sorry, I probably phrased the question not as precisely as I should have. I meant ideas by Lucas that he told to a C-canon author and were included in that C-canon work (even if the idea is, as you noted, is G-canon on a technical level). I'll edit the question to reflect that technicality. I won't downvote since the answer is incorrect only due to my not being precise, but the answer doesn't address the spirit of the question.

Comment: @DVK The rule is, if it come from Lucas, it's G-Canon : It's the **definition** of G-canon. Therefore, something cannot come from Lucas and be C-canon. There's no odd number that are even.

Comment: the facts are canon or not. E.g. you can gave G-canon fact in the middle of a book 99% of which is C-canon otherwise. That's straight from Leland Chee, NOT Wookiepedia

Comment: But Wookiepedia quote Leland Chee, the link is death but use the [mayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20070319051650/http://blogs.starwars.com/holocron/33)

Comment: Leland elaborated further, as I said. Basically, you say the book is C-canon just for simplicity's sake... but really it's individual facts in the database that have canon level. If the fact originated from Lucas, it's G-canon (no matter where it's in, in a movie or in a book). If with a book author, that fact is C-canon.

Answer (score 3):

According to IMDB,

- Lucas was a major [writer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024923/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers) for *Star Wars: The Force Unleashed,*

[image: George Lucas ... Characters and universe/story]

- The [creator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024923/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers) of the unreleased *Star Wars: Detours* (which has its own canon
  level),
- A [writer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158208/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers) for *Star Wars: Shadows of the Empire*,
- And a [writer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089110/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers) for *Ewoks: The Battle for Endor*.

There are also dozens of examples of him being credited for "Characters" but I assume you don't want those.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis/Legends) was a [Muun](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Muun/Legends) was not covered in G or T canon, but made part of EU C canon by [*Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_vs._Sith:_The_Essential_Guide_to_the_Force_(real-life_book)), and later by the novel [*Darth Plagueis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel)). In the [Behind the scenes section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis/Legends#The_Darth_Plagueis_novel) of Plagueis' Legends article on wookieepedia, it says it's been confirmed that George Lucas came up with this fact:

> A panel on continuity at the Celebration IV convention revealed that his identity as a Muun had originally come from George Lucas.